# Open a file type in Mac with a custom command

Tags: macos, applescript, macports, automator, geany

I am currently grading for a C++ class and want to be able to download all the files my students submit and when I click on them they open in Geany so I can compile them really quickly and run them.

When I ran linux I used Geany as my preferred IDE. I've switched to Mac and installed Geany via MacPorts. I currently run Geany by opening a terminal and calling it.

Is there a way to specify a custom command for a file type or will have to build an application to run Geany. Also how do I do that. I tried messing around with automator and applescripts, but couldn't get very far.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you want

Use Applications -> Automator -> Application -> Run Shell Script

Change the "Pass input"  to "as arguments"

Change the

```
 echo $f
```

to the full path to your geany executable.  Leave the $f

```
 /the/full/path/to/geany $f
```

Save the Automator app. Give it a name you like.

selecting Get Info (⌘I) in the Finder, and then setting Open with: to Geany and clicking the Change All... button. If that doesn't work I'll need to look into it further.

[Source](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5257325?start=0&tstart=0)